# How to insert dynamically a Table into a table cell into another Table?

Tags: c#, html

I'm working with a structure of tables; i have several small tables i want to include in a bigger table, inserting them into tablecells of this bigger table, but i don't know how to do it.

Is there any way to transform the small tables to code and use the TableCell.Text = "code of small table" or something like that?

I guess it is possible to do dynamically, but i can't figure out how to...

Comment: Dont forget to mark as accepted if it works for you

Comment: Yes, i did, excuse me. Solved now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .net to add control to prent control there is method `Controls.Add()` so your code will be

```
TableCell.Contols.Add(newtable);
```